# C getopt, have an argument that doesn't require a -x flag

Tags: c, getopt

You can use getopt to parse arguments in c, with a string containing the flags, if they are mandatory or not, if they take an argument...

Is it possible to have an argument that doesn't require any flag, like so ?

`./program -a arg1 arg2`

Here arg2 doesn't need any flag, yet it would still be parsed. Is it possible to do so with getopt ?

Comment: use argv[optind].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man 3 getopt`:

> ```
> extern int optind;
> ```
>
> If there are no more option characters, `getopt()` returns `-1`.  Then `optind` is the index in `argv` of the first `argv`-element that is not an option.

If `optind` is less than `argc`, read it, increment `optind`, and continue parsing.